# How to open .project using jcreator?

Tags: java, ide, jcreator

I have a java project which is written by JCreator.I've never use JC before(I'm a netbeans user)
I installed JCreator and now can't open the project.Maybe I don't know how... 
There is .project and .classpath files and src , bin and .settings folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JCreator to run a project it's enough to run Main.I didn't find anyway to open .project file but running Main was enough.

Comment: can you specify which file is Main?